# Flat symbol (special chars) not using text color on Samsung 12"

Tags: android, text, interface, fonts, ascii

Working on a music app and there is a way for users to add a text note. The text edit screen has a button for them to insert a flat '♭' symbol into their comment.

The button has a flat symbol on it which is appearing dark gray but set to white. Also when the symbol is added to the EditText text it also appears gray, unlike the rest of the text which follows the set color. I have tried using all of the fonts.

Note this only seems to happen on the Samsung 12" tablet so far. It may happen on others but the Galaxy Tab is working fine.

Comment: '♭' is a flat symbol, not sharp.

Comment: haha, that's why I'm a programmer. Thanks. Anyway ... solution?